# Pandas read CSV already delimited

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file which is structured as follows:

```
Data Download information etc.
Header1   Header2   Header3   Header4    ...
A         B         C         D          ...
E         F         G         H          ...
I         J         K         L          ...
...       ...       ...       ...        ...
```

Other than the first line, all headers and data are already delimited into columns. However, I am unable to find a method to read my CSV file.

```
[IN] df = pd.read_csv('path.csv', encoding='unicode_escape', skiprows=[1])

[OUT] pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 6 fields in line 16, saw 7
```

In total there are 50 columns. The data in line 16 is no different from other lines.

```
[IN] df = pd.read_csv('path.csv', skiprows=[1])

[OUT] UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 234375: invalid start byte
```

And if I use `skip_bad_lines` I get a df as output, however completely messed up, data from all 50 columns condensed into 5 columns and a ';' is added as delimiter within each column.

Anny suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

```
pd.read_csv('path.csv', encoding='unicode_escape', skiprows=[1])
```

skips the second row. This makes the first row (`Data Download information etc.`) the header, and messes up column detection.

You should use:

```
# skip 1 row
pd.read_csv('path.csv', encoding='unicode_escape', skiprows=1)
```

Or:

```
# skip the first row (0-based indexing)
pd.read_csv('path.csv', encoding='unicode_escape', skiprows=[0])
```

For more details, see the `skiprows` parameter in the [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) documentation:

> **skiprows** int, list of int or Callable, optional
>
> Line numbers to skip (0-indexed) or number of lines to skip (int) at the start of the file.
>
> If callable, the callable function will be evaluated against the row indices, returning True if the row should be skipped and False
> otherwise. An example of a valid callable argument would be `lambda x: x in [0, 2]`.

Output:

```
   Header1   Header2   Header3   Header4 
0  A         B         C         D       
1  E         F         G         H       
2  I         J         K         L
```

Comment: Facepalm. However, its not enough to fix my issue, still have a Parsewarning (error tokenizing data). If I also add sep=None, and engine='python' to avoid a final Parswarning, it works.